# SD card sometimes mounted as readonly on Ubuntu 22.04, mount used in a docker container

Tags: 22.04, docker, sd-card

On a Ubuntu 22.04 system a card reader is connected to a USB port. Since it's necessary to access the card reader in a Docker container, the volume is configured as follows in a `docker-compose.yml` file:

```
    volumes:
      - type: bind
        source: /media
        target: /media
        bind:
          propagation: shared
```

Most of the times this works fine, the docker container volume at `/media` is updated when a card is removed/inserted. The SD card is only mounted when a card is inserted. The OS mounts the card at `/media/username` and once removed, the OS unmounts it.

However sometimes it happens that when a card is inserted, the OS mounts it as read only, but the card itself is not readonly (the plastic write protection is not in place). The card is readonly in the OS and therefore also readonly in the Docker container. Reinserting the card sometimes resolves the problem but not always.

The card needs to be writable since the service running in the Docker container needs to delete the files on the card.

Could it be that this docker compose configuration part interferes with the mounting process? If not, what could be the cause of the readonly mounting issue?

Is there a better way to do the docker volume mapping of a SD card?